# Can a simple PHP For Each loop handle sending email to 10,000?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I'm sending an email to 10,000 emails using a PHP for each loop. Is there any reason why this isn't best practice for handling 10,000 emails? Could this execution hang? I want to be sure this will go out to all emails.

```
 foreach($thecustomer as $key => $value){
      $to = $customeremail; 
      $fromemail = $shopowner . " <" . $email . ">"; 
      $subject = $subject;
      $message = $body;
      $headers = "From:" . $email . "\n";
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 }
```

Comment: See: _max_execution_time_

Comment: It's a good practice to execute it in chunks (e.g.: send 1000, then another 1000...). I'd also suggest you to use a flag in the database (boolean, date, whatever) to set that the email has been sent in case you need to re run the same script (as you probably don't want to email the same person twice).

Comment: It isn't best practice to send a bunch of mails all at the same time. You'll be blacklisted if you keep it up.

Comment: Yes php has no problem doing that, however note that mail() will create a new connection to the mailserver, send the mail, and close the connection again, meaning you will also open & close connections 10,000 times!  while PEAR::Mail  PEAR::Mail_Queue packages will do it all in a single connection, thus being much faster.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with sending 10,000 emails at once. We send thousands of emails to subscribing customers every day--legally and ethically. The focus here should be on the technical implementation.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted. Stackoverlow never ceases to amaze me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes php has no problem doing that, however note that mail() will create a new connection to the mailserver, send the mail, and close the connection again, meaning you will also open & close connections 10,000 times! while [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) and  [PEAR::Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue) packages will do it all in a single connection, thus being much faster

to quote the mail() docs:

> Note:
>   It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>   For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and » PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

also make sure you have enough execution time, you can use
`set_time_limit(0);` to "never timeout"